# Tips for finding jobs writing compilers and/or operating systems? and, are the salaries of people with these jobs open knowledge?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, salary, computer-science

In the tech space, my dream job is writing compilers for new and various languages across different paradigms (think everything between Haskell, C#, C++, Smalltalk, JavaScript, prolog and LISP). I also have the related passion for Operating Systems and Processor Design (all the way from the transistors, logic gates and flipflops; through to the kernel; through the userspace, the shell and then to the GUI etc.).

However, over the whole decade or so I've been working in Tech, I've never seen an advert for these sorts of jobs (although admittedly, Google has been a recent exception in that they are explicitly recruiting for Fuschia development).

I have a hunch that such jobs are rare on the ground. Programming languages often get their start off the back of either a single celebrity tech nerd or a pair of them (cf, C, C++, Python). Every now and then a committee might produce a language spec and tech stack (eg Ada, COBOL, Haskell). I have a gut feeling that it's actually quite rare for a tech company to straight up decide to spend their tech talent developing such things, because it's a bit of a lottery as to whether or not the result will be profitable (i.e., just because you spend time and money creating a brand spankers snazzy new language/tech-stack, doesn't mean that the entire industry will immediately renounce their heathen C#/Java ways and migrate en masse to your new product).

I also have a hunch that, to take one example, there are only two or three people keeping the C# language standard up to date and maintaining the compilers. How does one land that job? Is it similar to the College of Cardinals where Anders Hejlsberg has to pass away before anyone else is allowed to step up?

So with that out of the way, my actual question: How does one manage to land a job writing compilers and/or maintaining the relevant language spec/standard? Are these jobs advertised anywhere? Or do you just have to be incredibly well connected?

Finally, I have a hunch that such roles pay way above average: Does anyone have any hard data on the salaries of people who invent languages and maintain the compilers? (I again suspect that its quite a dichotomy: the maintainer of the latest Lisp dialect might be making peanuts while the maintainers of Java, C#, C++ are presumably raking in M$ and Googlebucks)

Comment: [Principal Compiler Engineer, Arm](https://careers.arm.com/job/cambridge/principal-compiler-engineer/33099/12871339696). [Associate Software Engineer, C/C++ Developer Tools, Red Hat](https://global-redhat.icims.com/jobs/89378/associate-software-engineer---c-c%2b%2b-developer-tools/job). [Principal Software Engineer, GPU Compilers, Microsoft](https://careers.microsoft.com/us/en/job/1033281/Principal-Software-Engineer-GPU-Compilers) <- all those found just by searching for "compiler" on the main jobs page of some obvious companies. Where have you been looking?

Comment: Is this about being "connected", profitable, heathen code or just your hunch?

Answer (score 3):

Put simply, your understanding of the complexity of a modern optimising compiler toolchain is off by at least two orders of magnitude.

> I also have a hunch that, to take one example, there are only two or three people keeping the C# language standard up to date and maintaining the compilers

Absolutely not. I have no inside information, but the C#/.NET compiler team at Microsoft will be of the order of hundreds of people. Similarly, hundreds of people contribute to the GNU C/C++ and Clang/LLVM toolchains.

Similarly, no individual maintains the standard for any major libraries; they are all maintained by a committee - in the case of C#, this is [ECMA TC49-TG2](https://www.ecma-international.org/task-groups/tc49-tg2/). While you may recognise a familiar name as the convenor of that committee, decisions about the language are made by the community, not by one or two individuals.

Given this, I think the rest of your questions largely become moot: there are lots of jobs on compiler/developer tools teams, and these are available from entry-level upwards. Are they paid better than other software development roles with similar seniority? Not significantly, once other factors like location are taken into account.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't started writing your own compilers on the side, then you are very not likely to get such a job. What you will find out is that writing compilers is not just about the compiler, but also the run time environment. Secondly, writing compilers is also heavy into testing. Modern compilers have to pass a very serious test suite to get released. There might be more effort put into creating and maintaining the test suite than there is in the compiler.

To get experience with writing compilers, I suggest that you volunteer on one of the open source compiler projects. Then, when you apply for a compiler writing job, you can bring in your experience.

Comment: Counterpoint: the Associate Software Engineer job linked in my comment. Note that all the "experience with compiler stuff" requirements are optional, not mandatory.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Certainly so, but this post reads like someone who simply took one course and wants to get a job doing that not knowing the full ramifications of compiler writing. Thus, the suggestion to volunteer on an open source project might give him a better idea of what he is asking about.

Comment: Sure, there are a lot of mistaken assumptions in the original post, but I think the statement that you can't get a job writing compilers - or at least on the team that writes the compilers - without having worked on your own compiler is a bit overstated.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I said, "not likely", not "can't". I think your answer starts off better than mine, but we are both trying to say the same thing. If I were looking at a stack of resumes and someone has volunteered on an compiler project compared to someone who knows nothing, I'll take the person with experience. I was lucky to get a chance to work a little on the run time for one compiler and that was because I was part of a small systems programming team back when 64K RAM was a big computer.

Comment: You said "very not likely" which is pretty close to "can't" in my book. Is that possibly a typo for "not very likely"?